# Android: Overlay TextView on LockScreen

Tags: android, textview, overlay, android-windowmanager

[image: Concept]

Im trying to overlay a TextView on top of the LockScreen (Similar to how Android Overlays the time).

Note: I dont want to by-pass the lockscreen, but just draw on top of it (without interfering with any of the touch events).

I've tried using the following flags (in onCreate):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
    getWindow().addFlags(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

And applying the following Theme (to the specific activity):

```
   <style name="Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>   
</style>
```

But this draws on TOP of the lockscreen hiding the lockscreen and disabling all touch events.

Edit: **activity_overlay.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.coco.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest declaration of Activity (which inflates overlay_activity.xml)**

```
      <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Transparent" />
```

Comment: Can you show your actual layout file?

Comment: @mcwise Added the layout file. activity_overlay.xml . Also added the manifest declaration

Comment: Ive tried all combinations of Theme & Flags but none give the desired overlay. Also tried using the Flags from onCreate and onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: perhaps you need a lock screen widget?

Comment: Any code that you can share by using what Ive provided?

Comment: look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035202/how-to-suppress-notification-on-lock-screen-in-android-5-lollipop-but-let-it-i

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you want to display things out of your app activity, you can use a Service and WindowManager for that, the same way how Facebook Messenger and other floating windows apps works ;)

**LockScreenTextService.class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created on 2/20/2016.
 */
public class LockScreenTextService extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private boolean isShowing = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private TextView textview;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        //add textview and its properties
        textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Hello There!");
        textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white));
        textview.setTextSize(32f);

        //set parameters for the textview
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        //Register receiver for determining screen off and if user is present
        mReceiver = new LockScreenStateReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public class LockScreenStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //if screen is turn off show the textview
                if (!isShowing) {
                    windowManager.addView(textview, params);
                    isShowing = true;
                }
            }

            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                //Handle resuming events if user is present/screen is unlocked remove the textview immediately
                if (isShowing) {
                    windowManager.removeViewImmediate(textview);
                    isShowing = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //unregister receiver when the service is destroy
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }

        //remove view if it is showing and the service is destroy
        if (isShowing) {
            windowManager.removeViewImmediate(textview);
            isShowing = false;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**and add the necessary permission on AndroidManifest.xml and add the service**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.textonlockscreenusingservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/> //this

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".LockScreenTextService" /> //this

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Don't forget to start the service on onCreate() of your activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockScreenTextService.class);
    startService(intent);

}
```

**TextView showing on lockscreen**
[image: TextView showing on lockscreen]

**TextView removed when unlocked**
[image: TextView removed when unlocked]

Comment: I wasnt active for a few days. Did you get the bounty? This answer is correct

Comment: was able to get half of the bounty haha ;) don't worry

Comment: I've got this warning "**Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl -- permission denied for this window type**" while executing `windowManager.addView(textview, params);`, and so nothing was attached to the lock screen. Pls help..

Comment: Did you put necessary permission on manifest? "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>"

Comment: It appears that some kind of phones dose not work yet in Genymotion it works fine. Anyway thank you!

Comment: How to add margins or how can I change the position of this overlay view?

Comment: Is it possible to add a click event on the text ?

Comment: textview.setOnClickListener(); or such if it will work goodluck ;)

Comment: sorry as you can see this post is 2 years old already will update if I have time and be able to run it up on emulator ;)

Comment: Have anyone find solution for Orio? Somehow Truecaller did it.

Comment: If you wonder how to do the same on Oreo and don't want to waste days digging (Unlike me) here is the solution: 
1.
Use `AccessibilityService` Instead of the regular `Service` 
There the user has to enable your service in the Settings!

2.
Replace the `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` with `TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY`

Other places you will see the suggestion to use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` but it won't draw over the System UI!

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Android Lollipop (5.0), [support for lockscreen widgets has been removed (see the very bottom)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#managed_profiles). Instead, you should be using [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html), which can now appear on the lockscreen.