# Popup window above call screen in Android 7.0 version

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have to show an alert window over a call screen. Below Android 7 this functionality is working fine, but for Android 7 this is not working.

In a service am creating a window manager and added the view in but when the device is locked in the case of Android 7 it's not showing over call screen.

```
 mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                width - 20,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: Show some code. What have you done to try to solve your issue?

Comment: @Bryan in a service create a window manger and adding a view in it but it's not working in android 7.o

Comment: Have you given Overlay permission to app?

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt yes. when device is not locked it working fine but when device is locked it's not working

Comment: what do you mean by lock screen here,(Light is off or device locked?)

Comment: @ShashwatGupta device is locked by power button

Comment: may be on lock screen none of apps can draw overlays

Comment: please go through this link for LockScreenOverlay-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511570/7230266

Comment: @AnkitPawar Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY) was deprecated in API Level 26 for non-system apps and [no longer works as it used to](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#o-apps) for apps targeting Android 8.0; use [`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) instead.

Comment: still not working. i am trying to develope a caller id like true caller but my caller id not showing when device is locked in android 7 .