# Hide persistent notification

Tags: android, notifications

How i can hide a persistent notification in my app?

Currently my notification it's shown also in the lockscreen, but I don't want to. I only want the notification to appear when I swipe down the notification menu.

I know it is possible because i have an App called `WiFi ADB`, and it is doing exactly that. (TouchWiz Android 5.0.1)

This is the code of my notification (it is in a Service):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int _flags, int _startId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Subtitle")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1234, noti);
    mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(SERVICE_STARTED));
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress notification on lock screen in Android 5 (Lollipop) but let it in notification area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035202/how-to-suppress-notification-on-lock-screen-in-android-5-lollipop-but-let-it-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)` & `setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)` :

```
mNotification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Subtitle")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
        .build();
```

For [`VISIBILITY_SECRET`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#VISIBILITY_SECRET) :

> Notification visibility: Do not reveal any part of this notification on a secure lockscreen.

For [`PRIORITY_MIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN) :

> Lowest priority; these items might not be shown to the user except under special circumstances, such as detailed notification logs.

---

If you want to still show the icon in the status bar, there is no option for that but you can build an easy workaround by subscribing to `USER_PRESENT` & `SCREEN_OFF` events :

- cancel notification when you receive `SCREEN_OFF` events
- re-notify when you receive `USER_PRESENT`

register `BroadcastReceiver` & notify default notification :

```
mNotificationmanager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT");
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

mNotification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Subtitle")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
mNotificationmanager.notify(NOTIF_ID, mNotification);
```

In `BroadcastReceiver` cancel on `SCREEN_OFF`, notify on `USER_PRESENT` :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("test", intent.getAction());

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")) {
            mNotificationmanager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT")) {
            mNotificationmanager.notify(NOTIF_ID, mNotification);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! it is working! But is there a way to still show the icon in the status bar?

Comment: I've updated with an alternative solution if you want to have notification icon in status bar, notification record in notification menu while not having it in lockscreen